# How to use a javascript variable in script tag when using Wordpress wp_footer action?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is just a snippet of my function. But I need to grab the content of a Meta tag add it to the dataLayer. However, instead of this populating the variable type with the content, what I see is the literal word type. Is there anyway to do this. I would appreciate any help.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'mather_script');

function mather_script(){

   echo "
    <script> 

       var type = document.querySelector('meta[property~=\"og:type\"]');

       window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
       dataLayer.push({
         pageType: type, 
       });

    </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get used to separate the code in quotes, another mistake you made was repeating double quotes, check that in your script at the time of echo you used double quotes "" and then in the code fragment "og:type" you repeated them inside the echo, this is wrong and the script would not work.

You can try with the one I leave below in case it works correctly I will ask you to mark the answer as correct. thank you.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'mather_script');



    function mather_script(){
    
       echo "<script>" . "var type = document.querySelector" . "(" . 'meta[property~=\"og:type\"]' . ");" . " " .
    
           "window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];" . " " . 
           "dataLayer.push({
             pageType: type, 
           });" . " " . "</script>"
    };
```

Comment: Of course you can use another set of double-quotes, you just need to escape them with a backslash, which I have done. I do not want to sound unappreciative, but the code you provided I can tell you without trying will not work. Thank you anyway.